# How to convert InputStream to Json in Camel K

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I am trying to parse the response body of a http request in camel k. The response is json of the form `{"weather":{...}, foo:{...},...}` and I am only interested in the `weather` part. I tried the following approach:

```
// camel-k: language=java

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class Weather extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("timer:test?period=5000")
      .to("ahc:{{weather.uri}}")
      .log("${body.weather}");

  }
}
```

This leads to the following exception:
`org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: weather not found on bean: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@3584bf09 of type: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream on the exchange: Exchange[C8E32A97D83EBF3-000000000000001B]`

I am assuming that I first have to convert the `ByteArrayInputStream` to some more convenient data format like json to then access the individual fields.

What is the right approach to do this using camel k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out myself.

```
// camel-k: language=java

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class Weather extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("timer:test?period=5000")
      .to("ahc:{{weather.uri}}")
      .unmarshal().json()
      .transform(simple("${body[weather]}"))
      .log("${body}");

  }
}
```